# Xcode - duplicate Storyboard scene

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

Is there a quick way to duplicate a scene in Xcode's storyboard editor?

I'm looking for something akin to using option-drag to duplicate UI elements (`UIButton`, etc.) within a scene (or nib file). Copy-paste works, but awkwardly.

Comment: I hit that bug that clears the storyboard (everything disappears) every time I copy-paste. (Same w/ command-D.) Have to tab away and back to get everything back, and then the new scene is on top of the old one. Tell me that's not awkward. Just looking for something mouse-based. Not my normal bag, but I figure it'd speed things up.

Comment: sorry I havent had this issue, a scene is a viewcontroller and a view. If I want another I just copy and paste have had no problems.  Link it up to a segue and done. bug? I dunno

Comment: have you tried copy and pasting in the left pane where the object view is rather than in the design pane, might work.  Ill try it on my end.

Comment: i know what bug you are talking about. I had that issue also unfortunately. I did it the old style way. I made a new `UIViewController` and just copy pasted all my individual elements on the page. Also in storyboard, when you move the elements the segues also conform, which is an advantage.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I'm just using <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (Duplicate) for now, as it (AFAIK) is essentially a one-step copy-paste, and dealing with the bug.

Comment: Worked in Xcode 6.3.2. Take note, the duplicate scene will be directly on top of original scene. You have to click drag the duplicate scene to another location.

Comment: I've tried this for two scenes - one worked ok -but the other retained the original scenes name. why is this and how do I give the new object a name?

Comment: To answer questions similar toThe Huff's you'll need to set the scene's properties (such as Title) using the Attributes inspector, and change its class using the Identity Inspector.

Comment: Note that it will duplicate on top of the current scene, so drag duplicated scene.

Answer (score 12):

You can duplicate views if you drag them with ALT key. it does quickly

Answer (score 11):

Select the ViewController you want to duplicate. press `Command+C`(copy) then `Command+V`(paste).

Answer (score 8):

The new command is `Shift+Command+S`. You can also optionally click `File` and then `Duplicate`.

Comment: That is creating a new storyboard, not a new scene for the controller

Answer (score 5):

You can duplicate a view (or scene) easily by selecting the whole view, then copy and paste.

To copy and paste UI elements, select the element you want to copy, then copy it and paste it **in the original view**. Then drag the newly pasted element to the new view. Everything mouse-based.